# F# Struct with Interface, C# metadata does not show inheritance from Interface

Tags: c#, class, struct, interface, f#

So, bizarre issue I've got a struct and a record. Both implement the ITick interface, however when referencing Tick in C# the metadata shows no inheritance from the interface. For the RedisTick record type though the interface is inherited.

Have I missed something in my code / is this a bug / what's wrong with it?

**Interface**

```ml
type ITick = 
    abstract Symbol : string
    abstract Date : DateTime
    abstract Price : Decimal
    abstract Volume : int
```

**Struct**

```ml
type Tick(symbol : string, date : DateTime, price : Decimal, volume : int) = 
    struct
        member this.Symbol = symbol
        member this.Date = date
        member this.Price = price
        member this.Volume = volume
        interface ITick with
            member this.Symbol = this.Symbol
            member this.Date = this.Date
            member this.Price = this.Price
            member this.Volume = this.Volume
    end
```

**Record**

```ml
[<CLIMutable>]
type RedisTick = 
    { Symbol : string
      Date : DateTime
      Price : Decimal
      Volume : int }
    interface ITick with
        member this.Symbol = this.Symbol
        member this.Date = this.Date
        member this.Price = this.Price
        member this.Volume = this.Volume
```

### C# Metadata:

**Record in C#**

```
[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CLIMutableAttribute] [Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationMappingAttribute] 
public sealed class RedisTick : IEquatable<RedisTick>, IStructuralEquatable, IComparable<RedisTick>, IComparable, IStructuralComparable, ITick {
        public RedisTick();
        public RedisTick(string symbol, DateTime date, decimal price, int volume);

    [Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationMappingAttribute]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationMappingAttribute]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationMappingAttribute]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    [Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationMappingAttribute]
    public int Volume { get; set; }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override int CompareTo(object obj);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override int CompareTo(RedisTick obj);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override int CompareTo(object obj, IComparer comp);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override bool Equals(object obj);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override bool Equals(RedisTick obj);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override bool Equals(object obj, IEqualityComparer comp);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override int GetHashCode();
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override int GetHashCode(IEqualityComparer comp); }
```

**Struct in C#**

```
[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationMappingAttribute]
public struct Tick : IEquatable<Tick>, IStructuralEquatable, IComparable<Tick>, IComparable, IStructuralComparable
{
    public Tick(string symbol, DateTime date, decimal price, int volume);

    public DateTime Date { get; }
    public decimal Price { get; }
    public string Symbol { get; }
    public int Volume { get; }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override int CompareTo(object obj);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override int CompareTo(Tick obj);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override int CompareTo(object obj, IComparer comp);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override bool Equals(object obj);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override bool Equals(Tick obj);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override bool Equals(object obj, IEqualityComparer comp);
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override int GetHashCode();
    [CompilerGenerated]
    public sealed override int GetHashCode(IEqualityComparer comp);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about your setup? This works perfectly well for me in VS2015 and F# 4.0 on Windows. Also, just in case: have you tried rebuilding your F# project?

Comment: I have the same setup, and yep tried a clean and rebuild all. So your Tick structure viewed from C# implements the ITick interface? Mind posting your metadata, I'm intrigued!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** in VS2015 RC it has been fixed!